# Issue with making an hangman game in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to create an hangman game in UWP and I'm not quite sure where to type the button click event of each letter in the code in order to have it recognize all of the variables in MainPage without affecting functionality.

If possible to have the button clicks in a separate class, even better.
Would appreciate if you could help me, thanks in advance!

```
namespace Hangman
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        int _currentIndex;
        string _currentWord;
        string[] _strArr = { "ant", "bee", "spider", "mosquito" };
        int _difficulty = 1;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            _currentIndex = rnd.Next(0, 4);
            _currentWord = _strArr[_currentIndex];

            foreach (char c in _currentWord)
            {
                string _hiddenWord = string.Empty;
                foreach (char ch in _currentWord)
                {
                    _hiddenWord += "_" + (char)160;
                }
                _textBl.Text = _hiddenWord;
            }
        }

        private void a_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you want to capture the key press event of the keyboard or the input event of the `TextBox`?

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Hey, I want to capture Button clicks of buttons on my XML code. I've made a property like so `public char Key { get; set; }` and had each Button click insert a different value dependant on the letter, for example: on button_a, `Key = 'a';`. Now, my idea is to make a switch case that has a case for each value of the property 'Key' but now I'm not sure how to check which specific indexes in a string have a specific letter, maybe a loop over it but it seems inefficient to do so for every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to capture Button clicks of buttons on my XML code. I've made a property like so public char Key { get; set; } and had each Button click insert a different value dependant on the letter, for example: on button_a, Key = 'a';

I probably understand what you mean. You have a lot of buttons (like a button that makes up a keyboard). Each time you click the button, you get the button's identity and then type it into the text box.

You can use the `Button.Tag` property to record your key, like this:

```xml
<Button Tag="a" Content="A" Click="Button_Click" />
```

In code-behind, the `Button_Click` method has two parameters, where the `sender` refers to the Button that triggered the event, so you can convert it and get the `Tag` property.

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    string tag = btn.Tag.ToString();
    // Do Something
}
```

In this way, you can bind all the buttons to the same handler, which is very convenient.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to your XAML file where you design your UI, find the button and then add

```
<Button Content="Your Button Text" onClick="a_Click" />
```

there.